# Fetch all events for the next 24 hours, including current events in the Office365 API

Tags: api, events, calendar, office365

I'm using the following API call to fetch all events for the next 24h. The thing is, this doesn't return events that are currently active. Lets say an event started on 2018-08-01T13:00:00.000Z, this event isn't returned.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/calendars/<KEY>=/calendarView?startDateTime=2018-08-01T13:17:29.233Z&endDateTime=2018-08-02T13:17:29.233Z&orderby=start/dateTime&top=5
```

Now I know I can decrease the startTime to some hours before the current date/time and manually filter out all the old items except current ones, but what If an event takes a day, multiple days or a week? I would like Office365 to only return the items I need, so that is including the currently active items.

I can't find anything in the Office365 API documentation that points me in the right direction nor something that could lead to a workaround. Does anyone know how to fetch the current events as well but using the current date/time as "start date"?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do is with some help from Microsoft. I now use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/calendars//events with a $filter property containing the following:

```
Start/DateTime le '<current date/time>' and End/DateTime gt '<current date/time>' or Start/DateTime gt '<current date/time>'
```

This returns current events as well as future events.